# Not able to find the query portion in looped back request by HttpResponseRedirect | Session is not saving the key/value

Tags: django, session, session-cookies, httpresponse, django-settings

I am trying to redirect to another API for some random token generation and that will ultimately loop back to my current URL again, but when the redirected URL is actually looped back to the function I am not able to find the `QUERY_STRING` in `request.META`.

In the intermediate state I am able to see the query portion. The intermediate state is (I found by giving print statement) as below:

`https://mysite.domain.com/api/home/?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6qh`

In views.py:

```
def home(self, request):
    print("\nMeta: ", request.META) 
    # Prints -> 
    # Meta: {'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'REMOTE_ADDR': 'xx.xx.xx.xxx', 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'https://mysite.domain.com', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'wsgi.multithread': False, 'uwsgi.node': b'ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.aws.test.domain.com', 'wsgi.input': <uwsgi._Input object at 0x7f965c42b3a8>, 'CONTENT_TYPE': '', 'wsgi.multiprocess': False, 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '', 'REMOTE_PORT': '62724', 'REQUEST_SCHEME': 'https', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1', 'SERVER_NAME': 'mysite.domain.com', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'wsgi.errors': <_io.TextIOWrapper name=2 mode='w' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>, 'REQUEST_URI': '/dboardrpt/', 'HTTP_HOST': 'mysite.domain.com', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/etc/nginx/html', 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in function uwsgi_sendfile>, 'HTTP_REFERER': 'https://mysite.domain.com/api/home', 'wsgi.version': (1, 0), 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'https', 'HTTPS': 'on', 'uwsgi.version': b'2.0.14', 'SERVER_PORT': '443', 'wsgi.run_once': False, 'PATH_INFO': '/home/'}

    # Where the `QUERY_STRING` is blank, and that why the below if statement is failing.

    if (request.GET.get('token')):
        ...
        # Business logic follows....
        ...
    else:
        URL = "https://authenticate.domain.com/api/get-new-token/"
        params = {
          'redirect_uri': "https://mysite.domain.com/api/home/",
          'secret_key': settings.SECRET_KEY
        }
        return (URL + HttpResponseRedirect + '?' + urlencode(params))
```

My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'corsheaders',
   'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
   'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
```

The query portion is not getting save in session somehow. I tried the `python manage.py migrate` to to sync the `django_session` table.

Not sure whether I am missing something in `settings.py`

Comment: Can you confirm that `request.GET.get('token')` is also empty?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I have checked. The `request.GET` is returning a completely blank querydict. `{}`

Comment: And can you confirm that the redirect is actually going to `https://mysite.domain.com/api/home/?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6qh` ?

Comment: Yes, it is going to the `https://authenticate...` api and a new token is getting generated, that token I can see in URL as intermediate state. But when it is looped back to the first `if` block after coming back the `?token=xxxxx` portion is somehow vanished. But ideally it should be in `request.GET` querydict. Django is not able to save it is session/cookies.